# react toggling class, importing using module

Tags: css, reactjs, use-state

i am trying to toggle a class with useState, but i imported the class using module (not globally, xxx.module.css).
is it possible to toggle the class without changing them to global?

example:

```
import styles from 'xxx.module.css'

function app(){
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
return()
<div className={active ? "active" : " "}><p>Hy there!</p> </div>
<button onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>toggle me</button>

}
export default app
```

with a css

```
.active{
display: flex;
}
```

its something like that, but if i use module to import css it won't really work since it require {styles.active} (i've already tried changing the class name to {styles.active} its not really working).

is there any way to work around this? thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by changing them to global, but as far as importing stylesheets is concerned, it is hard to say without seeing your project structure and set up. But going by a popular one used with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet), you don't name the stylesheet being imported, you just put in it's proper path and just the import statement. So, something like this: `import 'myStylesheetName.css'`

Comment: You're close! `active ? "active" : " "` should be `active ? styles.active : ""`

Comment: Do you want to toggle the class? What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
import s from './x.module.css'
import {useState} from 'react'
const App = () => {
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
return (
  <div>
   <div className={active ? s.active : null}>Hi world!</div>
   <button onClick={()=> setActive(!active)}>Activate!</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

x.module.css:

```
.active {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library for this:

```
const className = classnames({ [styles.active]: active });
```

Alternatively, you can set up the functionality yourself:

```
const className = active ? styles.active : undefined;
```

and then: `<div className={className}>`

Answer (score 0):

You must use className as styles.active and it must not be between quotation marks.
So your division tag must like that:

```
<div className={active ? styles.active : " "}>
...some JSX...
</div>
```

---

PS: The code you write here to specifing the problem have full of errors. I don't think in real code you did this terrible mistakes but I want to indicate this stiutaion.